Improve on poor performance when rendering 10k triangles in a RUST-TAURI animation app
I am trying out some RUST code to compare it with qt5-c++ GUI performance for rendering meshes. I installed "rust  and a rust gui:tauri" in a Windows 10 PC (stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc - rustc 1.80.1)
I got a simple animation working to display sinusoidal circular waves in a 800X800 canvas - I am seeing only a 1.3-1.5 FPS end-to-end performance where its just rendering 12800 triangles in a mesh (data size 307200b).
The breakdown is as follows :

The Javascript front end takes 21ms to render 12800 triangles of a mesh (data size 307200b) onto a canvas


loop Time=763 : cycle=882 mesh=741 : render=21 FPS=1.31




for the following code
  while(notdone) {
    if (time >= totalTime) notdone = false;
    sTime = performance.now();
    let cTime = sTime - bTime;

    const meshElements = await invoke('animate_mesh', { width, height, numSeg, time });

    const mTime = performance.now();
    renderMesh(ctx, meshElements);
    const eTime = performance.now();

    const meshTime = mTime - sTime;
    const render = eTime - mTime;
    const loop = eTime - sTime;
    const fps = 1000 / loop;

    // Log FPS to the console
    console.log(`Frame loop=${loop.toFixed(0)} : cycle=${cTime.toFixed(0)}
                 mesh=${meshTime.toFixed(0)} :  render=${render.toFixed(0)}
                 fNum=${++fc}: FPS=${fps.toFixed(2)}`);

    time += 0.1; // Increment time for the next frame

    bTime = sTime;
  }


And the RUST backend only takes 2-3ms to generate the mesh :


animate_mesh len:12800 size1:307200  size2:0 time:2.7773ms




for the following code
fn animate_mesh(width: u32, height: u32, numSeg: u32, time: f64) -> Vec<Element> {
  let start_time = std::time::Instant::now(); // Start the timer
  //log::info!("animate_mesh...");
  let elements = sinusoidal_field(width, height, numSeg, time);
  let size1 = std::mem::size_of_val(&elements)*elements.len();

  let duration = start_time.elapsed(); // Measure the elapsed time
  let fps = 1.0 / duration.as_secs_f64(); // Calculate FPS

  //log::info!("animate_mesh dt:{:?} FPS: {:.2}", duration, fps); // Print FPS to console

  let len = elements.len() as usize;
  let mut elements1: Vec<Element> = Vec::with_capacity(len);
  let size2 = std::mem::size_of_val(&elements1)*elements1.len();

  log::info!( "animate_mesh len:{:?} size1:{:?}  size2:{:?} time:{:?} FPS: {:.2}",
              len, size1, size2, duration, fps ); // Print FPS to console
  elements
}

Which implies the RUST-TAURI UX is giving only 300-400 kbps for the above setup.
BUT I get 200FPS if I return 0 bytes ('elements1' above instead of 'elements') !!
>>loop Time=5 : cycle=4 mesh=5 :  render=0 FPS=196.08

Question :

Is there something basically wrong with the above setup ? (as RPC performance can be as high as 200 FPS i.e 30-40 mbps when returning nothing)
How can I speed up the performance - I will be happy with 5-10 FPS for 100-200k elements.

UPADTE
interestingly binary buffer encoding and decoding performs worse than serde serialization and seserialization
let mut buffer = Vec::new();
buffer.extend_from_slice(&v0.x.to_le_bytes());  // for all coods and values

followed by javascript
const dataView = new DataView(buffer);
val = dataView.getFloat64(offset, true);

performs ~10% slower...


loop=960 : cycle=973 : mesh=887 : render=73 FPS=1.04


** NOTE ** Serializing whole vector at once instead of item by item should be faster but for me the decode never worked at the front end - it looks like there are serialization headers inserted in the buffer that I couldnt decode in javascript yet.
so I am back to tweaking qt5 graphics for now.

@DatGeoudon - the entire backend including sinusoidal_field only takes 2-3ms - see above. In fact - calling sinusoidal_field but just ignoring its return value and returning 0 len vector takes the FPS to 200

Just a gut feeling: since JS doesn't support inlined structures, Vec<Element> needs to be converted to a JS array of Element references, thereby reallocating each item individually on the heap. That's a lot. I'd try to pass a for a more JS-friendly data type to ease the load on invoke internals.

@aedm - good guess and yes I thought of that - but expected tauri to handle that behind the scenes to avoid binary-to-text on the return path... maybe I am wrong and thats unavoidable - no idea as I am playing with this just for a couple of days now.

Hm, looks like the situation is even more dire, Tauri uses serde to process arguments and return values. That's a significant overhead. You might be better off calling WASM from JS -- or just implement your calculation in JS directly.

@aedm - Thanks - I will look into what serde and WASM are... but this is a trial to see if RUST UX loop is faster than processing 100-200k QGraphicsItem on a QGraphicsScene... so meshing has to be in the backend.

interestingly passing a binary buffer and decoding mesh elements at front end was slightly slower than serde serialize and deserialize ! see update...
